# How to become administrator on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator

I want to become administrator(I mean super admin with all authority) on Windows 10.

I activated administrator account as below;

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

But problem is I still got nearly no authority on Windows 10 files. I think administrator account is just a simple user account named "administrator".

I am trying to delete a file under;

```
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\0efe6e576f3de2a15e6fe0ba6da24f3a
```

but problem is even Administrator has no authority.

[image]

Is there any admin account on Windows 10? I mean for example who can delete all files?

Comment: The directory your viewing by designed isn't given permissions to Administrator users

Answer (score 0):

#### Any user that is a member of the built-in Administrators group (which includes the Administrator *user* you have activated) has **full access** to the computer.

> I am trying to delete a file under;
>
> > C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\0efe6e576f3de2a15e6fe0ba6da24f3a
>
> but problem is even Administrator has no authority.

In order to delete a folder, you need the correct NTFS permissions on the object. In your case Administrators don't have the necessary permissions by default.

However, the story doesn't end there.

Administrators have a special user right which allows them to *take ownership* of any filesystem object, even if they don't have permission to the object. In turn, an object's owner can always change the permissions on the owned object, again, even if they don't have any permissions to it.

So for an Administrator that cannot access an object, the process looks like this:

1. **Take ownership of object** (right-click object> Properties> Security> Advanced> Ownership)
2. **Grant himself the NTFS Full Control permission to the object** (right-click object> Properties> Security> Edit)

---

**Caution:**  When Administrators aren't granted permission to files and folders by default, there's a good reason for that. Especially when it comes to system objects, exercise caution when changing permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [takeown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) command to take ownership of the object (file or directory) first as follows:

```
takeown /r C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\0efe6e576f3de2a15e6fe0ba6da24f3a
```

It would take ownership *recursively* meaning applied to all subdirectories and files within, if any.

There's also a [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) page about the command.

Also you might note the `/a` switch which gives ownership to the Administrators local **group**.

---

Issue `net localgroup administrators` to learn more about the group.

---

`takeown` is an *external command*, meaning it's actually an executable file residing in `C:\Windows\System32` folder as `takeown.exe`.

---

I assume `%windir%` and `%systemroot%` is `C:\Windows`.

---

Which also makes `%homedrive%` and `%systemdrive%` `C:`.